# Simple HTML dom not scraping

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I want to **scrape data from Zoover** but when I try to do this with Simple HTML dom it just returns nothing and the HTML page stops afterwards.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    include_once('libs/simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file('http://www.zoover.nl/indonesie/lombok/senggigi/campi-sorga/villa');

    foreach($html->find('#testimonials-list > ul > li > article') as $element) {
         echo $element['header > h3']->plaintext . '<br>';
      }
?>
```

Hope someone can help me, A newbie to `Simple HTML dom`.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your code, and it appears you are trying to access the $element object as an array, so after testing your code, you should try this:

```
<?php
    include_once('libs/simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file('http://www.zoover.nl/indonesie/lombok/senggigi/campi-sorga/villa');
    foreach ($html->find('#testimonials-list > ul > li > article') as $element) {
        echo $element->find('h3')[0]->text() . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

it worked for me.

Comment: Nope. Didn't fix it

Comment: that's strange, because i tested it and it worked, what is the php error that you get?
the only thing that I can think of, is that you might have a problem with your include_once statement...